# LINQ Group-by clause on Enumerable field

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I'm running into a bit of a problem writing a LINQ Query.

Given this data

```
Object       ID       Items
------       --       -----
Object1       1       [1,2,4]
Object2       2       [2]
Object3       3       [2,4]
Object4       4       [1]
```

I want to group on the IDS inside my `Items` property

The end result should be something like this

```
ItemID     Objects
------     ------------------------------------
1          [Object1, Object2, Object3, Object4]
2          [Object1, Object2, Object3]
4          [Object1, Object3]
```

In which "Objects" contains the entire "object", or the properties that I wish to select.

Any help with this?
It's probably pretty basic, but I can't wrap my head around it right now.

Comment: Can you explain the logic how to transform the first table to the second?

Comment: how do you know which `ItemID`s to look for? is it always from `1` to (known) `n`? union of all `Items` lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following pseudocode

```
var result = objects.SelectMany ( o=>o.Items.Select (x=>new {item=x,objectid=o.object)).GroupBy (x=>x.item).ToArray()
 // objects -> collection of objects in question
//Items.Select => create list of item to object mapping
//objects.SelectMany -> Flattens item to object mapping into IEnumerable
//.GroupBy => groups the result by itemid
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Late accept because I was cursing at the code until I finally noticed I erroneously put a wrong bracket somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
var results = from o in source
              from i in o.Items
              group o.Object by i into g
              select new { ItemId = g.Key, Objects = g.ToList() }
```

Comment: Glancing over the code, I assume it does the same as Tilak's code. I accepted his answer because I prefer LINQ method syntax over query syntax.